# Strong typing multiple variables for one array / object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Using TypeScript, I have created the following global variables and given them appropriate data types:

```
reviewkey: string;
title: string;
reviewer: string;
category: string;
header: string;
desc: string;
body: string;
largeimagelink: string;
smallimagelink: string;
feature: string;
previousdate: Date;
spoilers: string;
```

After some rethinking, I'd like to create these variables into one single array or object which will allow me to significantly reduce my code to something much more readable with the use of a loop.

However, doing this

```
reviewProps = [
    reviewkey: string;
    title: string;
    reviewer: string;
    category: string;
    header: string;
    desc: string;
    body: string;
    largeimagelink: string;
    smallimagelink: string;
    feature: string;
    previousdate: Date;
    spoilers: string;
]
```

results in errors.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: if you have array you can't have properties, but you can do 
const test: [string, string, number] = [ 'text', 'text', 1];

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the properties/variables, or how specifically would you use the data structure you are looking for?

Comment: @Floremin Ideally, I'd like to iterate over each variable.

Comment: What would you do in each iteration?

Comment: @Floremin I would use the value for a query to Firebase. So instead of specifying a snapshot for each variable 12 times, I could loop over the array / object to do this with one loop that would only require a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

> into one single array or object

## Fix

Use an object (not an array). Example:

```
type reviewProps = {
    reviewkey: string;
    title: string;
    reviewer: string;
    category: string;
    header: string;
    desc: string;
    body: string;
    largeimagelink: string;
    smallimagelink: string;
    feature: string;
    previousdate: Date;
    spoilers: string;
}
```

Comment: in this case, the OP current case, I would go for an `Interface` instead